# OpenLDAP multi-tenant like ACL

Tags: openldap

Is it possible to write an ACL for OpenLDAP which implements a multi-user and multi-tenancy environment. I mean to really secure the DIT using one rule and to match dynamically every customer.

Example DIT:

```
ROOT
..customer1
....Users
......Admin
......User
....objects
..customer2
....Users
......Admin
......User
....objects
```

What I want is that Admin user from customer1 may only see and write objects from customer1 and customer2 users may only see and write customer2 objects. The same goes for User of each customer, but in read-only mode.

I didn't get such an ACL working and only found examples to write below the users entry in the tree, but nothing to get 2 levels up and allow to write below that. Someone has an idea how to apply such an ACL?

Thanks-

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that what you want here is OpenLDAP's [ACL feature called sets](http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/1133.html)

Try something *like* this:

```
olcAccess: to dn.regex="^o=[^,]+,dc=example,dc=com$"
  by set="this/-*/manager/member* & user" write   
  by set="this/-*/manager & user" write
  by set="([ldap:///cn=Admin,ou=Users,] + this + [??sub?objectClass=inetOrgPerson]) & user" write
  by set="([ldap:///] + this + [??sub?objectClass=inetOrgPerson]) & user" read
  by * none
```

1. Identifies the objects to apply the rule to. In this case, it assumes each "client" object has a DN like "o=Client Company Name,dc=example,dc=com"
2. allows a member (recursively resolved, i.e. where a group is a member of a group) of a group assigned to the "manager" attribute of the client object (or any parent object) to write to the client object
3. allows a user directly assigned to the "manager" attribute of client object (or any parent object) to write to the client object
4. allows the user with an RDN cn=Admin,ou=Users relative to the Client object to write to it
5. allows any descendant user object of the client object to read it

Comment: Hi Stephen, this looks interesting and I will probably try this in the future, as for now I implemented the ACL inside my application, which makes it less robust and secure. Thanks!

Comment: No worries at all. I only noticed the original Question date after I'd written most of the answer.

If you do come back to the issue in the future and have issues, let me know!